# Python IRC bot only admin

Tags: python, bots, irc

I'd like to ask how can I make my python irc bot run commands only given by specified nick ?

My bot has Skybot - Python IRC bot core, it's based on it.

That's the module that imports in every command

```
import inspect
import re


def _hook_add(func, add, name=''):
if not hasattr(func, '_hook'):
    func._hook = []
func._hook.append(add)

if not hasattr(func, '_filename'):
    func._filename = func.func_code.co_filename

if not hasattr(func, '_args'):
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)
    if name:
        n_args = len(argspec.args)
        if argspec.defaults:
            n_args -= len(argspec.defaults)
        if argspec.keywords:
            n_args -= 1
        if argspec.varargs:
            n_args -= 1
        if n_args != 1:
            err = '%ss must take 1 non-keyword argument (%s)' % (name,
                        func.__name__)
            raise ValueError(err)

    args = []
    if argspec.defaults:
        end = bool(argspec.keywords) + bool(argspec.varargs)
        args.extend(argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):
                    end if end else None])
    if argspec.keywords:
        args.append(0)  # means kwargs present
    func._args = args

if not hasattr(func, '_thread'):  # does function run in its own thread?
    func._thread = False


def sieve(func):
    if func.func_code.co_argcount != 5:
        raise ValueError(
                'sieves must take 5 arguments: (bot, input, func, type, args)')
    _hook_add(func, ['sieve', (func,)])
    return func

def command(arg=None, **kwargs):
    args = {}

def command_wrapper(func):
    args.setdefault('name', func.func_name)
    _hook_add(func, ['command', (func, args)], 'command')
    return func

if kwargs or not inspect.isfunction(arg):
    if arg is not None:
        args['name'] = arg
    args.update(kwargs)
    return command_wrapper
else:
    return command_wrapper(arg)


def event(arg=None, **kwargs):
    args = kwargs

def event_wrapper(func):
    args['name'] = func.func_name
    args.setdefault('events', ['*'])
    _hook_add(func, ['event', (func, args)], 'event')
    return func

if inspect.isfunction(arg):
    return event_wrapper(arg, kwargs)
else:
    if arg is not None:
        args['events'] = arg.split()
    return event_wrapper


def singlethread(func):
    func._thread = True
    return func


def regex(regex, flags=0, **kwargs):
    args = kwargs

def regex_wrapper(func):
    args['name'] = func.func_name
    args['regex'] = regex
    args['re'] = re.compile(regex, flags)
    _hook_add(func, ['regex', (func, args)], 'regex')
    return func

if inspect.isfunction(regex):
    raise ValueError("regex decorators require a regex to match against")
else:
    return regex_wrapper
```

and that's how a simple command works:

```
from util import hook, http

@hook.command
def calc(inp):
    '''.calc <term> google calc result'''

    h = http.get_html('http://www.google.com/search', q=inp)

    m = h.xpath('//h2[@class="r"]/text()')

    if not m:
        return "Could not calculate " + inp

    res = ' '.join(m[0].split())

    return res
```

Also, I'd like to make it to have 2 admins, like only 2 people will be able to command it.I'd have done that myself, but looking at code I have no idea what  to do :?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `nick` keyword argument to your function, then check that against a list of nicks allowed to execute administrator commands:

```
administrators = ('nick1', 'nick2')

@hook.command
def someadmincommand(inp, nick=''):
    if nick not in administratiors:
        return 'I don't think so, {0}'.format(nick)

    # `nick` is an administrator, do your worst
```

Comment: That's what I wrote, and I get this error:

>  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "core\reload.py", line 89,
> in reload
>     eval(code, namespace)   File "plugins\ping.py", line 5, in <module>
>     def ping(nick="",say=None):   File "plugins\util\hook.py", line 63, in command
>     return command_wrapper(arg)   File "plugins\util\hook.py", line 54, in command_wrapper
>     _hook_add(func, ['command', (func, args)], 'command')   File "plugins\util\hook.py", line 26, in _hook_add
>     raise ValueError(err) ValueError: commands must take 1 non-keyword argument (ping)

Comment: Here is the code: 
from util import hook
    @hook.command("p")
    @hook.command
    def ping(nick="",say=None):
    administrators = ('tom', 'john')
    if nick not in administratiors:
    return "no"
    if nick in administrators:
    return "success"

Comment: @TomJenkins: You forgot the `inp` argument, you cannot just drop that.

Comment: Ok, I've added inp too. And it still gives me an error.from util import hook

@hook.command("p")
@hook.command
def ping(inp,nick="",say=None):
 administrators = ('tom', 'john')
 if nick not in administratiors:
   return "no"
 if nick in administrators:
   return "succes" 
Here is the error: 

    File "core\main.py", line 66, in run
    out = func(input.inp, **kw)
    File "plugins\ping.py", line 7, in ping
    if nick not in administratiors:
NameError: global name 'administratiors' is not defined